# Redirect all from http to https except contact page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

How do I redirect all pages on a site from https to http except the /contact page which I always want to be redirected to the https domain?

I can redirect all from http to https as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

However, I'm having trouble adding the exception for the contact page which I want to always redirect from http to https

**update**

I've added the rules as suggested but /contact is now redirecting to /index.php?q=contact.

I'm using ModX which has the rules:

```
# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Why is this conflicting with the new rule to redirect /contact (http) to /contact (https)?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/contact\/
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]    

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/contact\/ 
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

//Turn https on for /page/contact
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page/contact
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

//Turn https off everthing but /page/contact
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page/contact
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The first rule set will make sure the page /page/contact will redirected back to `https` if they are accessed via `http`. The second rule set will redirect all page to http that are accessed by `https` except /page/contact.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/contact$
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^contact$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

You can test your `.htaccess` file using [this online tool](http://htaccess.mwl.be/) (note that it doesn't includes all Apache functionalities and the result might slightly differ from your production server but works well for simple rules).

Comment: Thanks for that. The tool is especially helpful :) However, the /contact page is redirect to /index.php?q=contact. Do you know what could be causing this? (I've added some details to my question)