# let's encrypt auto-rule to redirect trafic from http to https excepted some files

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, https, url-rewriting, lets-encrypt

My Let's encrypt cerbot (on apache 2.4) has made an auto-redirection from http trafic to https what is very appreciate.

But in some cases, I need to access some files from http protocol (here `image.jpg`).

> I readed other questions about redirection except one folder, or some pages, but it doesn't work for me.

Here is my code :

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.ch [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =upload.domain.ch [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.ch
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^image.jpg
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will need to tell us _why_ what you read in other answers "doesn't work " for you, otherwise we can only repeat what you already read. So what happened?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, So here in my code, I tried to apply this solutions https://stackoverflow.com/a/38220432/2282880 but replacng folder by my image and it still redirects when I call image url.

Comment: One thing that sticks out here: ``RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^image.jpg`` won't work, since the REQUEST_URI is an _absolute_ path. So it should be ``RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/image.jpg``

Comment: Working :) thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear that, have a wonderful day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slash was missing in image path (related vs absolute path). 
Thanks to @arkascha for help.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.ch [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =upload.domain.ch [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.ch
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/image.jpg
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```